# Emailing reports with the extracted data from PL/SQL PROC

Tags: email, plsql, report

My objective is to email the data retrieved from Oracle PL/SQL Procedure. UTL_SMTP package has been disabled in my Office and I need to find an alternative way to do this.

It would be much appreciated If someone can guide me here.

Thanks,
Sekar

Answer (score 1):

If `UTL_SMTP` is disabled, use `UTL_MAIL` instead.

Although, that's rather strange - you're required to send mails, but yet, package used to do that is disabled. How come?